# How to change the ordering of columns in MUI's DataGrid when row grouping is enabled?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

As you can see in [this code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-brook-s2y4fl?file=/demo.tsx), the "Company" column comes third in the column config array but appears visually as the first one in the table. This is because the row grouping automatically makes the groupable column the first column.

[This MUI webpage on column order says that the order is dictated by the order of the objects in the config](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-ordering/). But it does not say how to override it when row grouping is on.

Would appreciate any help.